# Can't connect to port 53 UDP on DigitalOcean/Linode

Tags: ubuntu, bind, digital-ocean, linode

I'm trying to set up my own DNS nameserver for a CTF challenge. I have an Ubuntu 20.04 droplet running on DigitalOcean with Bind9 installed. It works fine when testing on that machine (e.g. `nslookup ubuntu.com [public_ip]`), but I can't connect to it from the outside world (i.e. my computer).

I have enabled TCP/UCP on port 53 in the DigitalOcean firewall:
[firewall config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bgar.png)

I have disabled ufw:

```
$ ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I have allowed everything in iptables (based on https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/resources/troubleshooting/#finding-the-iptables-firewall-settings):

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
sudo ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -F
```

bind9 is listening on the port:

```
$ netstat -tulpen | grep 53
tcp        0      0 10.106.0.2:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        32489      2469/named
tcp        0      0 10.16.0.5:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        32487      2469/named
tcp        0      0 [public_ip]:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        32485      2469/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        32483      2469/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        32496      2469/named
tcp6       0      0 [redacted]              :::*                    LISTEN      112        32495      2469/named
tcp6       0      0 [redacted]              :::*                    LISTEN      112        32493      2469/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      112        32491      2469/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      112        32497      2469/named
udp        0      0 10.106.0.2:53           0.0.0.0:*                           112        32488      2469/named
udp        0      0 10.16.0.5:53            0.0.0.0:*                           112        32486      2469/named
udp        0      0 [public_ip]:53          0.0.0.0:*                           112        32484      2469/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           112        32482      2469/named
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                112        32490      2469/named
udp6       0      0 [redacted]              :::*                                112        32492      2469/named
udp6       0      0 [redacted]              :::*                                112        32494      2469/named
```

I did a test with port 54. I opened in in the DigitalOcean firewall, started `nc -ul 54` on the droplet and connected **successfully** with `nc -u [public_ip] 54` from my computer. I then stopped `named` and tried to do the same on port 53, but I couldn't connect.

What else might be blocking the port?

**Edit**: same issue on Linode, which would suggest that it's not specific to DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I realized that this was because of my VPN. If I turn it off I can connect with `nc` or `dig` (if `named` is running). I'm not sure why that is, but it solves the problem for now.